# Proving function of a martingale is integrable and measurable

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(X_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N_0}}$ be a martingale with values in $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $|X_n - X_{n-1}| = 1$ and $f: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ an arbitrary map. I need to show that $f$ is integrable and measurable.

Given that a martingale by definition has to satisfy the condition $\mathbb{E}[|X_n|] < \infty,$ I guess one should use this in proving $\mathbb{E}[|f(X)|]<\infty.$ But the assumption is that $f$ is arbitrary. How should one approach the problem ? Thanks.

Comment: There are multiple errors in your statement. Please see if you can proof read and correct the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is discrete, you are (presumably) using the discrete topology and hence the $\sigma$-algebra is the powerset $2^{\mathbb{Z}}$.  This makes every map $f: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow X$ measurable, no matter what the set $X$ is.

Since $|X_n - X_{n-1}| = 1$, we have that $|X_n| \le n$.  Since $f: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $|f(k)| < \infty$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, so $|f(X_n)| \le \sup_{|k| \le n} |f(k)| < \infty$.  This implies $|f(X_n)|$ is in fact bounded (by a constant depending on $n$), and in particular it is integrable.

Comment: I think this is the solution the OP is going for, but one thing that seems unclear is what is $X_0$. One can have $X_0$ be a non-degenerate $\mathbb{Z}$ valued random variable, for instance such that $E(|f(X_0)|)=\infty$, and then the conclusion is no longer clear. I think the OP must add a couple conditions.